# If covariance equals variance, what does that say about the correlation?

Tags: correlation, covariance

If we know covariance is equal to variance, can we make any assumptions about correlation?

Comment: Variance of what? There have to be multiple random variables to have a covariance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if Covariance(x,y) = Var(x), can we make any assumptions about correlation?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation $\rho(x,y)$ of two variables $x$ and $y$ is defined as their covariance standardized by the product of their standard deviations: $\rho(x,y) = \frac{cov(x,y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} $. If $cov(x,y) = \sigma_x^2$, you are left with $\rho(x,y) = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}$.

Therefore, when we do not know $\sigma_y$, we only know that $\rho(x,y)>0$, since a standard deviation cannot be negative. However, we can infer something about $\sigma_y$ from this, namely that it must be larger or equal to $\sigma_x$, otherwise we would calculate the correlation to larger than 1.

Comment: We know that $\rho\ge 0$. // We also know that $X$ and $Y$ have the same units (meters, seconds, Daves, etc).

Comment: @Dave true. I was thinking in terms of effect size only. Would you mind elaborating on the units aspect? If $x$ is measured in Daves and $y$ in Pals, what would be the problem here?

Comment: If $X$ is measured in feet and $Y$ is measured in kilograms, then the units of $cov(X,Y)$ will be $\text{feet}*\text{kilograms}$, while $var(X)$ will have units of $\text{feet}^2$. Certainly no number of $\text{feet}*\text{kilograms}$ can equal any number of $\text{feet}^2$. If the units are the same, though, then the values can be equal.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of what we were repeatedly taught in 7th grade :) "If Adam was born in 2000 and the current year is 2010, then Adam is 10" - "what 10? 10 seconds? 10 water melons? 10 horses?"